# Get HttpServletRequest from another server and set cookie into httpServletResponse and send back origin server was request come

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

I am using spring boot to build example SSO include guest Server at 8280 and authenticate server at 8080 , when access 8280, user will be redirect to server 8080 , login to authority. Now i want get all info of HttpServletRequest, and set cookie for guest server by httpServletResponse. How to i make it ?

I am using spring boot in both server
Here is my code

- Configuration Filter Bean at 8280

```
@Configuration
public class FilterBeanRegistrationConfig {

    @Value("${services.auth}")
    private String authService;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean <JwtFilter> jwtFilter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<JwtFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new JwtFilter());
        registrationBean.setInitParameters(Collections.singletonMap("services.auth", authService));
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/protected-resource");
        return registrationBean;
    }

} // END
```

- application.propertie at 8280

```
services.auth=http://localhost:8080/login
server.port=8280
```

- AuthenticatedUser.java

```
public class AuthenticatedUser {

    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String resourcesUrl;
    private String token;
    public AuthenticatedUser(){

    }

    public AuthenticatedUser(String email, String username, String password, String resourcesUrl, String token) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.resourcesUrl = resourcesUrl;
        this.token = token;
    }

// getter and setter


} // end class
```

- Controller at 8080

```
@Controller
public class LoginControllerFromVue {

    private static final String jwtTokenCookieName = "JWT-TOKEN";
    private static final String signingKey = "signingKey";

    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public RedirectView method(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse , HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){

        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("http://localhost:4000/login?");
        redirectView.setPropagateQueryParams(true);
        return redirectView;

    }

    @PostMapping("/api/login")
    public String loginUser(@RequestBody AuthenticatedUser theUser , HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

        if (theUser == null || userService.findUserByUsername(theUser.getUsername()) == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (! passwordEncoder.matches(theUser.getPassword(),userService.findUserByUsername(theUser.getUsername()).getPassword())) {
            return null;
        }

        String token = JwtUtil.generateToken(signingKey, theUser.getUsername());
        CookieUtil.create(httpServletResponse, jwtTokenCookieName, token, false, -1, httpServletRequest.getServerName());

         return "redirect:"+theUser.getResourcesUrl();

    }

}
```

- Config Axios in Vuejs

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  }
});
```

- Login.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="submitform">
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="loginUser">
    <div v-if="!submitted" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" required v-model="user.username" name="username">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="age">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" required v-model="user.password" name="password">
        </div>

        <div id="error">
          <span v-if="error">Username or Password invalid</span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>

    <hr>
    <button v-on:click="getPathResources" class="btn btn-warning">Get Resources</button>
      |
    <button v-on:click="authorisedRedirect" class="btn btn-warning">Appcept Redirect</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import http from "../http-common";

export default {
  name: "login-User",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        id: 0,
        email : "",
        username: "",
        password: "",
        // resourcesUrl:location.host
        resourcesUrl : this.$route.query.redirect
      },
      error: false,
      submitted: false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    loginUser() {
      var data = {
        username: this.user.username,
        password: this.user.password,
        // resourcesUrl:location.host
        resourcesUrl : this.$route.query.redirect
      };
      http
        .post("/login", data)
        .then(model => {
          // this.user.id = response.data.id;
          console.log(model.data);

          if (model.data !== "") {

            this.$router.push('/authorised');

            this.submitted = true;
          } else {
            this.submitted = false;
            this.user.username = "";
            this.user.password = "";
            this.error = true;
          }

        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        }); 
    },
    getPathResources(){
      // var currentServername = location.hostname;
      var currentHost = location.host;
      var currentUrl = location.pathname;
        console.log(currentHost + currentUrl);
        console.log(this.$route.query.redirect);
      },
    authorisedRedirect(){
        window.open("http://localhost:8280/protected-resource", "_blank");
      }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.submitform {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245)
}
#error {
  background-color: beige;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>
```

When I log in with a valid account, I still cannot transfer to 8280 and still remain in the login page, it seems that setting the cookie to the 8280 server has not been successfully implemented by httpservletResponse. how to i setup it or any other solution to it work , if anyone know where's this problem please tell he how to sovle it and i appreciate!!!